# SSIS Catalog - All Executions report only shows #Error in all headings and hyperlinks

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm running an SSIS package on a recent install of SQL Server 2016. Recently the All Axecutions report of the Integrations Services Catalogs SSISDB started looking like the screenshot below. The package that is executed on a 5 minute basis runs fine. No errors. I can see the data being transferred as expected. Something is wrong with this report. I did some searching around and can't seem to find anything.

Anybody have any ideas as to what is wrong? Why is it showing #Error everywhere?

[image]

Comment: some 'not-so-helpful' reply from microsoft : https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3103853/ssis-built-in-execution-reports-are-broken-in-ssms-2016-v13-0-15800-18

Answer (score 29):

**Solution: Restart SSMS.**

I can reproduce this error with on SSMS 13.0.16106.4 / SQL Server 13.0.4206.0 (Although the reports was working for a period, the the issue came back).

With the SQL same user, but running SSMS 12.0.5000.0 (from a remote desktop) the reports were fine.

Another user with SSMS 14.0.17177.0 has never had the issue.

Restarting the server had no effect.

I restarted SSMS 13.0.16106.4, which solved the issue. This could be a SSMS memory issue.

Also posted on: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3103853/ssis-built-in-execution-reports-are-broken-in-ssms-2016-v13-0-15800-18

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: More context added.

Comment: Yep, thanks, restarting SSMS solved it for me. This problem occurred after our update schedule.  Using SSMS 17.9 and SQL Server 2017

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Using SSMS Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 14.0.17285.0. Solved this by closing SSMS and restarting it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem and initially thought it was due to using the latest SSMS package - 17.1 on Windows 10 - but others with the same setup were not getting the errors.

I then ran the configuration for SSRS (which had been installed but not configured). This created the reporting server databases but made no difference. I don't think SSIS reporting uses SSRS anyway but not sure.

I then ran Windows update and it installed latest .NET 4.7 packages.

After a re-boot SSIS reporting was back to normal!

So one or combination of what I did above together with a re-boot made the difference but equally it may just have been a re-boot that was required.

This was on my development machine and I have been backing up and restoring the SSISDB from production to my development environment - this may have a bearing on attempting to re-producing this problem but I have not experienced it since and after fully deleting and restoring the SSISDB.

Hope that helps?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Out of the blue the report started working correctly again. I don't know what I did to make it work but it was nothing intentional.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. Turns out I had dropped some windows groups from the database I was loading data into (which was on a completely different server). When I added them back, the reports worked and didn't show `#error`

This makes absolutely no sense of course, but I thought I'd document it in case it helps or jogs someones memory

Comment: That shouldn't be relevant. One workstation has an issue and another does not against the same server.

Comment: Where does it say that?

Comment: What do you mean? Two different computers are looking at the same server and expressing different behavior. After workstation restart everything went to normal.

Comment: I’ve read through this whole thread and none of the questions or answers mention anything about two workstations.

Comment: That is obvious troubleshooting. If two different workstations with exactly same SSMS version experiencing different output connecting to the same server - means one of them have a problem.

Comment: I'm not sure why would you jump into a three year old post and propose a test case that never existed? I agree that testing two workstations is an excellent troubleshooting step (and also that basic troubleshooting is often sorely missing on this site) but I don't see it's relevance to my post.

Comment: Just had that issue on my current project and there was some controversy about it. So, I've done some research and hit that page. I think a lot of people in the world have that issue and they hit that page constantly. It would be nice to provide the best solution for them.

Comment: It would be fantastic to have a clear canonical answer but I guess this happens for a few different reasons. That's why when I find an problem without an answer I try and add what worked for me in case it helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

RE: "I restarted SSMS 13.0.16106.4, which solved the issue. This could be a SSMS memory issue." from @James Bourne

RE: "Using SSMS Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 14.0.17285.0. Solved this by closing SSMS and restarting it." from @Ade

I had some very large nHibernate queries (captured from Extended Events) open in a couple of SSMS tabs.  I closed each tab and restarted SSMS version 18.8.

Problem solved!